# Change PivotTable date field column format then sort field

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a PivotTable with a single date column field. I want to have the column grouped by 7 days and then show it ascending order. The problem is that when grouped, items show up like:

`5/1/13 - 5/7/13, 5/16/13 - 5/21/13, 5/22/13 - 5/29/13, 5/8/13 - 5/15/13`

As you can see, 5/8... is in the wrong spot. The reason is that, at this point, the field is recognized as solely text, but not a date.

My attempt at a fix was to change the date format to "mm/dd/yy" to sort better. So for instance, the date would read as: `05/01/13 - 05/07/13`. But the issue was that when I went to group again, the date automatically changed back to what it was.

is there a way to pro-grammatically group the pivotTable columns but still keep that date format, so that it can sort in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was supposed to be a last resort but eventually I had to make an array of the beginning dates in my date ranges, change the format of the date to `mm/dd/yyyy`, sort it and then adjust the position of pivotItems based on the array index positioning. I did this by having the array items as a key in a map, with the value being the actual pivotitem name.

```
Sub TryAndSort()

 Dim w As Worksheet, p As PivotTable, pi As PivotItem
 Dim arr() As Variant
 Dim map As New collection

     Set w = Sheets("data")
        i = 0
        For Each pi In w.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("date").PivotItems
            If pi.Visible Then
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next

     ReDim arr(1 To i)
        i = 1
        For Each pi In w.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("date").PivotItems
            If pi.Visible Then
                j = Split(pi.Name, " - ")(0)
                k = Format(j, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                    arr(i) = k
                    map.Add CStr(pi.Name), CStr(k)
                    i = i + 1
            End If
        Next

    Call QuickSort(arr, 1, UBound(arr)) '<--- the sorting method

    For Each p In w.PivotTables
        For t = 1 To UBound(arr)
            p.PivotFields("date").PivotItems(map.Item(arr(t))).Position = t
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```